# Can I set a breakpoint in a dynamically loaded .jar (with ClassLoaders)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classloader, breakpoints, bytecode

I'm writing a program that loads the .jar for the game Minecraft, does some ASM trickery, dumps it to a folder of .class files, and loads that folder with a ClassLoader (then starts the game). I want to set a breakpoint in one of those class files, to help debugging. Adding the Minecraft .jar as a dependency in IntelliJ breaks the program (as it doesn't load the modified class).

How do I do that, if it's even possible?

Comment: AFAIK, For Debugging, you would need to code. You would want to debug a class which is modified and thus you would not have the code.

Comment: @SandeepJindal IntelliJ 14 has a built-in decompiler, if that helps.

Comment: Do you have source code of those class files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but not directly. What you need to do is to place the breakpoint on the part of YOUR code that calls (uses) the JAR in question, and then STEP INTO the JAR code.

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: I cannot. Find out how to set a breakpoint on your favorite IDE, and then do it. It is not rocket science. If you use Eclipse, a simple mouse "right-click" on the document pane left margin and the option to "Toggle Breakpoint" shows up on the popup menu. Then, you have to learn how to launch the application in Debug Mode. Again, do the 2-minute research on how to do this using your favorite IDE.

Comment: That is the obvious part. What do you mean by "step into"?

Comment: There are many controls (buttons) to step through the code. They are: resume, step-over, step-out, and step-into (there might be others). Of course, I am strictly speaking about Eclipse; so there might be differences with other IDEs, but similar nevertheless. The "Step-into" button allows you to get inside the method a particular line of code is calling. I suggest you read your IDE documentation. Explaining this takes more than what I can type in here.

Answer (score 0):

typically, debugging information is added (or not) by `javac` ([see options information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)) So if you don't have the source code, or even if you do but the bytecode has been compiled without debug information, there isn't going to be a way to do this.

Comment: You could still step through it, it's just not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Option one: you can add your JAR as a dependency, but change its type to "Provided".

If that does not work: I assume you have many libraries configured in your project. Try adding the sources of your Minecraft jar to any of those libraries (Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> choose a jar or directory with source files). Now, using Go to class, open the class you want to set a breakpoint in and set that breakpoint. If IntelliJ IDEA does not refuse to do this, and if you ASM manipulation does not remove debug information, when the class is dynamically loaded at runtime, the debugger will stop at the breakpoint.